# Is there any way to check and release database lock using java?

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle

I am using java, Spring , oracle data base. Some times my database tables are locked. Every time i am going to database and closing the session. Is there any way   to check weather a table or row is locked and release the lock on it using java? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below SQL query first to identify currently locked objects:

```
SELECT O.OBJECT_NAME, S.SID, S.SERIAL#, P.SPID, S.PROGRAM, SQ.SQL_FULLTEXT, 
S.LOGON_TIME FROM V$LOCKED_OBJECT L, DBA_OBJECTS O, V$SESSION S, V$PROCESS P,
V$SQL SQ WHERE L.OBJECT_ID = O.OBJECT_ID AND L.SESSION_ID = S.SID AND
S.PADDR = P.ADDR AND S.SQL_ADDRESS = SQ.ADDRESS;
```

You can even look for particular table by filtering with `OBJECT_NAME` value. 
Once you have identified session to be killed, you can kill it using:

```
alter system kill session 'SID,SERIAL#';
```

Comment: I would strongly advice against this! Using Java to kill sessions on the DB can lead to massive problems if a bug gets introduced at some point!

Comment: Agreed. All of this should be handled by DBA and application shouldn't even have access to these tables or views.